# Where does the file go when i run pg_dump using Windows?

Tags: postgresql

I connect to my remote database in Azure ok using psql , then i run the below command but i cant find the file? I want to send the backup file to my windows hard disk

```
pg_dump -E utf8 --clean --if-exists --no-owner --verbose --no-password -f > c:\backup_file.tar
```

Comment: Don't use `>` in combination with `-f`, remove the redirection (`>`)

Comment: did that same issue : pg_dump -E utf8 --clean --if-exists --no-owner --verbose --no-password -f c:\backup_file.tar

Comment: What happens if you do `-f c:/backup_file.tar`?  FYI, `pg_dump` with no `-F` option produces a plain text file not a `tar` file.

Comment: You have to run pg_dump from the OS command shell.  You do not run it from inside `psql`.